# d3 fisheye(d) returns undefined object

Tags: d3.js

So I am working with the d3 fisheye plugin, and I am having some pretty basic problems.
I implemented this very basic code, pretty much a direct copy from here https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/fisheye

```
    fisheye = d3.fisheye.circular()
        .radius(200)
        .distortion(2);

    //initialize fisheye
    chart.on("mousemove", function() {
        fisheye.focus(d3.mouse(this));

        dataPoint.each(function(d) { d.fisheye = fisheye(d); })
            .attr('y', function(d){ return d.fisheye.y; })
            .attr('x', function(d){ return d.fisheye.x; });
    });
```

But `d.fisheye.x` and `d.fisheye.y` are undefined. In fact, looking at `fisheye(d)`, it returns:

```
  {x: undefined, y: undefined, z: 1}
```

On the other hand, `d3.mouse(this)` is properly returning an array.

Does any one have suggestion on why this might be occurring?

More code: by the way, the code is like this because it is inside a ext-js panel, so each function (drawWords is a property of this object). It is kind of complicated which is why I hesitated to post it all, and this is still not all the code, but the relevant part I think. I didn't include the initialization of any of the other global variables, or helper functions.

```
//imagine some sort of onload function
    onLoad: function () {
         this.drawWords();
         this.animateVis();
    }

,drawWords: function () {
    toolObject = this;
    var h = this.body.getHeight(),
        w = this.body.getWidth();

    //initialize word text
    this.dataPoint = this.chart.selectAll('text')
        .data(toolObject.termometerData, function (d) {return d.word;})
      .enter().append('text')
        .attr('class', 'points')
        .attr('id', function(d) {return d.word + '-point';})
        .attr('x', function() {
            return toolObject.xScale(toolObject.shiftCount);
        })
        .attr('y', function (d) {
            return toolObject.fanVertical(d, toolObject.shiftCount);
        })
        .attr('transform', function (d) {
            var thisXPosition = toolObject.xScale(toolObject.shiftCount),
                thisYPosition = toolObject.fanVertical(d, toolObject.shiftCount);
            return 'translate(0, 0) rotate(-20 ' + thisXPosition + ' ' + thisYPosition + ')';
        })
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('fill-opacity', function (d) {return toolObject.opacityScale(0);})
        .text(function(d) {return d.word;});

    this.applyFisheye();
 }

 ,fisheye: d3.fisheye.circular()
        .radius(200)
        .distortion(2)

 ,applyFisheye: function () {
    var toolObject = this;

    //initialize fisheye
    this.chart.on("mousemove", function() {

        fisheye.focus(d3.mouse(this));

        toolObject.dataPoint.each(function(d) { d.fisheye = toolObject.fisheye(d); })
            .attr('y', function(d){ return d.fisheye.y; })
            .attr('x', function(d){ return d.fisheye.x; })
            .attr('transform', function(d){
                return 'translate(0, 0) rotate(-20 ' + d.fisheye.x + ' '+ d.fisheye.y + ')';
            });
    });
 }
 ,animateVis: function () {
    var toolObject = this;
    var h = this.body.getHeight(),
        w = this.body.getWidth();

    var tick;

    if(this.animationIdArray.length < 1){
        tick = setInterval(function(){
            animate();
        }, this.duration);
        this.animationIdArray.push(tick);
    }

    function animate() {
        if(toolObject.shiftCount < toolObject.numDataPoints){
            toolObject.shiftCount++;

            //animate words
            toolObject.dataPoint.transition()
                .duration(toolObject.duration)
                .ease('linear')
                .attr('x', function(d){ return toolObject.xScale(toolObject.shiftCount - 1); })
                .attr('y', function(d){ return toolObject.fanVertical(d, toolObject.shiftCount - 1); })
                .attr('transform', function(d){
                    var thisXPosition = toolObject.xScale(toolObject.shiftCount - 1),
                        thisYPosition = toolObject.fanVertical(d, toolObject.shiftCount - 1);
                    return 'translate(0, 0) rotate(-20 ' + thisXPosition + ' '+ thisYPosition + ')';
                })
                .attr('fill-opacity', function(d){
                    return toolObject.opacityScale(d.series[toolObject.shiftCount - 1].freq);
                });

            toolObject.applyFisheye();
        }else{
            clearInterval(tick);
            toolObject.animationIdArray.shift();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your complete code please?

Comment: There you go! Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Did you check if the `x` and `y` attributes of your data points are set correctly?

Comment: They are! Everything is animating and displaying properly. The only problem is that I can't seem to add a fisheye effect overtop of it all.

Answer (score 1):

fisheye assumes that the x and y coordinates of your objects are defined by keys named "x" and "y". It's probably enough (but possibly overkill, depending how often this code is called) to use

```
this.dataPoint
    .each(function(d) { 
        d.x = toolObject.xScale(toolObject.shiftCount);
        d.y = toolObject.fanVertical(d, toolObject.shiftCount)
    .attr('x', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('y', function(d) { return d.y; });
```

when you `//initialize word text`